# Excel on Mac Conditional Formatting - Exceptions

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, conditional-formatting

I am having some trouble with conditional formatting on the mac.
I have two columns of numbers that when multiplied together give a product in a third column. As the third column relates to a risk status, I want it to automatically colour code. I can do a traffic light cell background based on the number. However, there are a few number combinations that throw up the same product but need to be coloured differenty.

i.e. the product of 1x4 and 4x1 have the same product but should be coloured differently. (there are a few of these)

I have tried using the AND function, but can't seem to get any conditions right.
Does anyone have any thoughts on how to help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up a table like this:

[image: table]

You can set your conditional formatting like this:
[image: formatting]

And as you can see, that only highlights column C if the product is less than 5 (or whatever you need it to be) AND column A is less than column B (or whatever other condition you need).

Comment: Thank you. I must have been making a silly error in the AND formula